# How to avoid including unused library in Android (or any Java) project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project uses 2 third party libraries (both more than 10 MB in size) for some speech processing features. I need only one of them at a time (almost like a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering#Software_component)), a decision I make during build time. I have consumed methods of both libraries in the same module as of now. My *build.gradle* has flags like these :

> buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_LIB_ONE", "true"
>   buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_LIB_TWO", "false"

In my Java code, I have checks like this :

```
if (BuildConfig.USE_LIB_ONE) {
    A.method();
} else if(BuildConfig.USE_LIB_TWO) {
    B.method();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to conditionally compile LIBRARY_ONE or LIBRARY_TWO based on buildConfigField? My APK is getting bulky even when I don't use the other library.
2. Is there a cleaner way to design such projects? My codebase is bloated with if/else checks of the same condition.
3. I guess gradle product flavors may help in this case, but I don't know a lot about it. Can someone please confirm if product flavors do help in conditional compilation?
4. Can [ServiceLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) be of any help here? On a non-Android project I would be possibly using it, but Android implementation sounds buggy based on some SO posts.

My question is NOT a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560372/how-to-avoid-unused-resources-and-code-from-an-android-library-project-getting-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is an issue for your question [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162285)

but for a workaround you can use flavor + build type configuration in your build.gradle like this

```
configurations {
  libOneReleaseCompile
  libTwoReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    libOneReleaseCompile 'lib.one.speech'
    libTwoReleaseCompile 'lib.two.speech'
}
```